# Сенсорное управление игроком в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

я начинающий разработчик игр, поэтому постоянно сталкиваюсь с проблемами, которые решаю, но вот с этой у меня загвоздка. В моей игре на андроид нужно двигать главный игровой объект пальцем, не отрывая его, только вправо или влево. То есть представьте, что есть какая-то полоса препятствий, и объекту надо её преодолеть, вот мне и надо чтобы, если палец влево, то он тоже влево, и наоборот. Я знаю про touch, но вот как согласовать передвижение,  мне не понятно. Заранее спасибо!(желательно, чтобы работало на всём экране, как я понимаю глобальный тач)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот равномерное передвижение за пальцем (без поворота)

```
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position,
                Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), moveSpeed);
        
        }
```

в moveSpeed загрузить скорость "1f"